# useradd Does Not Create a Group in SUSE

Tags: opensuse, useradd

I maintain a package that is built for debian, RedHat, and SUSE Linux distributions.  Part of the post install script follows:

```
/usr/sbin/useradd -r -d /var/opt/CampbellSci/LoggerNet loggernet
```

This command appears to work in other distributions but, under SUSE, the "loggernet" group is not being created and the home directory was created under the "root" group.  According to the man page for useradd, the group is supposed to be automatically created unless the -g -N, or -U option is used.  Is there any reason why SUSE is failing to create the appropriate group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual page says something different.  Quoting from OpenSUSE 13:

> By default, a group will also be created for the new user (see **`-g`**, **`-N`**,
>   **`-U`**, and **`USERGROUPS_ENAB`**).

and

> **`-g`**, **`--gid`** *GROUP*
>   The group name or number of the user's initial login group. The
>   group name must exist. A group number must refer to an already
>   existing group.
>
> If not specified, the behavior of **`useradd`** will depend on the
>   **`USERGROUPS_ENAB`** variable in `/etc/login.defs`. If this variable is
>   set to **yes** (or **`-U`**/**`--user-group`** is specified on the command line), a
>   group will be created for the user, with the same name as her
>   loginname. If the variable is set to no (or **`-N`**/**`--no-user-group`** is
>   specified on the command line), `useradd` will set the primary group
>   of the new user to the value specified by the GROUP variable in
>   `/etc/default/useradd`, or 100 by default.

In my OpenSUSE 13 VM, the setting in `/etc/login.defs` is (the default) **no**.

In OpenSUSE 12, this feature did not exist.